# How come the last item count is not filtering on delete?

Tags: javascript

I have a todo list with CRUD. I just implemented a task counter to show the number of tasks left to complete. The count increments/decrements with checking/unchecking items and decrements on deleting items. Except there is one problem. For some reason on the last item deleted, the count stays at 1 instead of going to 0. [Full Codepen](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/rNmKvpe)

Here is what I tried:

```
function renderTaskCount() {
    const incompleteTaskCount = todos.filter((item) => !item.completed).length;
    const taskString = incompleteTaskCount === 1 ? 'task' : 'tasks';
    listCountElement.innerText = `${incompleteTaskCount} ${taskString} remaining`;
    return incompleteTaskCount;
}

const renderTodos = () => {
    ul.innerHTML = '';
    todos.forEach((item) => {
        let li = document.createElement('LI');
        li.setAttribute('class', 'item');
        li.setAttribute('data-key', item.id);
        const itemText = createTodoText(item);
        const cb = buildCheckbox(item);
        const db = buildDeleteButton(item);
        li.append(cb);
        li.append(db);
        li.append(itemText);
        ul.append(li);
        //update height of textarea
        updateHeight(itemText);
        renderTaskCount();
    });
};
```

Comment: Your code (read with the minimal info given) does not imply that should happen at all, so maybe you are just not removing the last item?

Comment: You shouldn't use `if ( input !== '' ) {` instead use `if ( input.trim() !== '' ) {`

Comment: @decpk I will make that change. Good to know. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
const renderTodos = () => {
    ul.innerHTML = '';
    todos.forEach((item) => {
        let li = document.createElement('LI');
        li.setAttribute('class', 'item');
        li.setAttribute('data-key', item.id);
        const itemText = createTodoText(item);
        const cb = buildCheckbox(item);
        const db = buildDeleteButton(item);
        li.append(cb);
        li.append(db);
        li.append(itemText);
        ul.append(li);
        //update height of textarea
        updateHeight(itemText);
        renderTaskCount();
    });
};
```

where `renderTaskCount` updates the count - which is done at the end of each iteration. So if the `todos` array is empty, the count will never be updated. You need

```
const renderTodos = () => {
    ul.innerHTML = '';
    todos.forEach((item) => {
        // ...
    });
    renderTaskCount();
};
```

so that whether `renderTaskCount` executes whether or not the `todos` array is populated.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I am still learning where and how to put logic. thank you